# VS2012 + Nuget: MvcMailer Reference not being added after installing packages

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, mvcmailer

I have seemingly messed something up in my VS2012 solution and cannot figure out what has changed. I am installing a package through "Manage Nuget Packages" window (right-click on "References" in project). The install succeeds, however, the reference under my project does not show (as it has before) the package (in this case MvcMailer).

Now, I can do stuff in the package manager console, like scaffold some stuff using

```
Scaffold Mailer.Razor UserMailer Welcome,PasswordReset
```

and that succeeds. However, when I build my project I get a ton of errors on all the MvcMailer related stuff. Previously I tried manually adding the reference (from the ~/packages folder), and it shows up as a reference in the project but I still get the errors.

I don't know what's going on. Any thoughts?